# What is the proper Twig syntax to display a ACF custom field linked to a Taxonomy term

Tags: twig, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

What would be the proper Twig syntax to print display a custom Taxonomy name of (genres) The ACF field name is book_genre and a the custom Taxonomy of "Business" is selected in this WordPress custom-post, The Twig syntax here `{{ post.book_genre }}` only outputs the ID of the Taxonomy on the page, but I need it to print the Taxonomy name of: "Business" I have also tried `{{ post.terms('category') }}` to no avail this just prints "Array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally was able to figure it out, it seems like `{{ post.meta('book_genre') }}` did what I needed it to do and print out the term name of "Business" (example only)

However in the ACF Groups the Return Value of "Term Object" has to be selected.